# Rewrite Dynamic URL to Root Domain Using Apache

Tags: apache, url, dns, url-rewriting, root

Using Apache's RewriteRule, how can I make it serve:

mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=home_page

as simply:

mydomain.com/

Without actually having a physical index.html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying the question in the comments, the poster wants 'http://mydomain.com' to internally redirect to 'http://mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=home_page' (without changing the URL in the browser's address bar). Adding the following to .htaccess should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ webpage.php?name=home_page [L]
```

Comment: Arthur, mydomain.com/ should display mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=home_page, since I have no index.html file in the root. Your suggestion gave me a server error.

Comment: I'm sorry, that still doesn't clarify the question. Are you maybe trying to make it so that when a user goes to 'http://mydomain.com' they are redirected to 'http://mydomin.com/webpage.php?name=home_page' rather than what I suggested above?

Comment: No, the opposite. When a user enters mydomain.com in the address bar, mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=home_page should load. But the address bar should just display mydomain.com instead of the whole address. The above suggestion gave me a server error.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ webpage.php?name=home_page [L]`
Should do what you want - I'll update my answer above.